# Lost privileges - no more suspend, mounting partitions needs password

Tags: mount, permissions, suspend

I am a bit stumped at the moment. I am running a Xenial system.

After a system update, there is no more entry to suspend the system, only shutdown (extremely annoying) and furthermore, every time I want to mount a partition via click in Nautilus, the system asks for a password and the same is true when I want to shut the system down via the GUI (somewhat annoying).

Checking the syslog, I found a problem with dconf. That was solved by making `~/.cache/dconf` belong to me instead of root again. Unfortunately, that did not solve the main problem.

Does anyone have an idea where I should start looking or better still, how to fix this? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

chessplayer

Comment: Could it be that other folders are also owned by root? If you have been running graphical apps with `sudo` that pretty much guarantees it.

Comment: Sounds like it could be something related to policykit /pklocalauthority

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, **CelticWarrior**, you nailed it and I had not noticed before that for whatever reason varíous hidden directories in my home folder suddenly belonged to root.

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 .hiddenfolder
```

then got everything back to normal again